# Vignette ads applying to form submit button

Tags: javascript, adsense

I've noticed that google adsense vignette ads are performing well on my site, but they do not appear when the primary function is performed- notably the clicking of a form submit button.

I can't find any reference in google's documentation about what specific links the ads will attach to, but using the debugger it seems to work on hard links on the page, which includes links on images.

Is there any known way to make these work on form submit buttons, or a good workaround that will enable them- such as using an href link that then submits the form via script?

Here is an example:
https://lagged.com/en/g/elastic-man

Every time you press "Play Now" comes the call of this advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

These ads have a higher cost than other Google ads, so it is not triggered every time you click on the links, after you click and it is triggered, it has a time interval to be released again. I just don't know how to specify, how often.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).